# How to visualize large graphs with directed edge bundling?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm wondering if anyone has implemented edge bundled graph plotting?

An important paper is ["Force-Directed Edge Bundling for Graph Visualization"](https://classes.engineering.wustl.edu/cse557/readings/holten-edgebundling.pdf) by Danny Holten and Jarke J. van Wijk.

Comment: While the paper is nice, can you expound upon it in your question? Links are fragile, so the more information that you add to your question, the longer they will remain relevant.

Comment: Looks like a really intricate application of the [EdgeRenderingFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EdgeRenderingFunction.html) option to `GraphPlot`.

Comment: @Verbeia it looks like more than that to me. It bundles edges that go in similar directions together, increasing their relative weight, and they peal off from the bundle near their nodes. (Fig. 8 is a good one to look at to see this.) This reduces the visual complexity of network.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`CommunityGraphPlot` has this feature implemented internally:

```
g = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "DolphinSocialNetwork"}];
CommunityGraphPlot[g]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The information about bundling is calculated by `CommunityGraphPlot` (i.e. it is not supplied with the example data), though unfortunately there are no documented options available to finetune the bundling (but see below), only the region (`CommunityRegionStyle`) and boundary styles (`CommunityBoundaryStyle`).

Though one can extract from the community graph the `BezierCurve` that generates the bundled edges (with low opacity `EdgeStyle` by default), it will contain references to vertex coordinates like `DynamicLocation["VertexID$1", Automatic, Center]`. Unfortunate again that due to the dynamical nature of a `CommunityGraphPlot`, ordinary `Graph` functions like `VertexList` or `PropertyValue[{g, 1}, VertexCoordinates]` will fail, so there is no easy way to extract the real vertex coordinates which otherwise could have been matched with the various `"VertexID$1"` references.

The method to find communities can be customized with `FindGraphCommunities`.

### Undocumented functionality

You have to dig deep to ultimately find any bundling-related code in `` GraphComputation`GraphCommunitiesPlotDump`communitiesPlot ``. It accepts the following internal options (above default ones):

```
 "EdgeLayout" -> Automatic
 "CommunityEdgeWeight" -> Automatic
 "CommunityRegionFunction" -> Automatic
```

If `"EdgeLayout"` has the value `"DividedEdgeBundling"`, the following suboptions are available to control the bundling process (with their defaults):

```
"CoulombConstant" -> 4.5
"VelocityDamping" -> 1
"SmoothEdge" -> True
```

Examining its internal usage and a bit of experimentation yielded the following results:

```
SetProperty[g, {GraphLayout -> {"EdgeLayout" -> {"DividedEdgeBundling",
      "CoulombConstant" -> 5, "VelocityDamping" -> .6, "SmoothEdge" -> True},
    "VertexLayout" -> {Automatic}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
SetProperty[g, {GraphLayout -> {"EdgeLayout" -> {"DividedEdgeBundling", 
      "CoulombConstant" -> 100, "VelocityDamping" -> .5, "SmoothEdge" -> False}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
SetProperty[g, {
  GraphLayout -> {"EdgeLayout" -> {"DividedEdgeBundling", 
      "CoulombConstant" -> 44, "VelocityDamping" -> .87, "SmoothEdge" -> False}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
SetProperty[g, {
  GraphLayout -> {"EdgeLayout" -> {"DividedEdgeBundling", 
      "CoulombConstant" -> 100, "VelocityDamping" -> .5, "SmoothEdge" -> False},
    "VertexLayout" -> {"SpringEmbedding", "EdgeWeighted" -> True,
       "Multilevel" -> False}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For larger graphs it really helps to use transparent edges:

```
sm = SocialMediaData["Facebook", "FriendNetwork"];
{
 SetProperty[sm, {ImageSize -> 300, GraphLayout -> {"EdgeLayout" -> None}}],
 SetProperty[sm,
  {ImageSize -> 300, EdgeStyle -> Opacity@.1,
   GraphLayout -> {"EdgeLayout" -> {"DividedEdgeBundling", 
       "CoulombConstant" -> 500, "VelocityDamping" -> .5, "SmoothEdge" -> False}}}]
 }
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in M10, I don't quite have enough time to spelunk what's changed but I'll come back if possible soon with a comment - your bio say's your on M9 still

Comment: @Martin I'm on v10 now and it still works exactly the same way (though it generates slightly different graphs for the last example due to changes in my Facebook account). Could you please specify where the discrepancy is at your end?

Comment: I get this http://i.imgur.com/dLq6XPa.png in a clean kernel, which is slightly odd.

Comment: @Martin It seems like something is set prior to plotting with e.g. `SetOptions[Graph, ...]` or similar. You're missing vertex shapes as well. Is this the result when you start with a fresh kernel?

Comment: even with a fresh kernel I get this. This is very strange, I'll look into it - thanks for replying.

Comment: More complete sub-option list found in v10: `{"NewForce","Connectivity","Compatibility","SmoothEdge","Threshold","SpringConstant","CoulombConstant","CoulombDecay","VelocityDamping","LaneWidth"}`.