# How to use the "EdgeLayout" suboption of GraphLayout?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

According to the documentation, [`GraphLayout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GraphLayout.html) has an EdgeBundling suboption, which can take the following values:

- `"DividedEdgeBundling"`
- `"HierarchicalEdgeBundling"`
- `"StraightLine"`

What does each do, what suboptions do they have, and how do I use them?

---

Partial answer:

`"StraightLine"` seems self explanatory, but not that it's not the default:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`"DividedEdgeBundling"` is described by István [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40111/12).

**That leaves `"HierarchicalEdgeBundling"`**, which I cannot figure out. It seems to behave the same as `"StraightLine"` in naive attempts to use it.

The suboptions of these can be discovered by passing a wrong value and looking at the error message:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This also reveals that there are several more suboptions to DividedEdgeBundling than the linked post above shows.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[Link to Community semi-cross-post](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/573131?p_p_auth=yEe2Gqxr)

Comment: Related: [(5308)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40111/17).

Comment: @Silvia Thanks!  I actually found this and linked it in the question.  So DividedEdgeBundling is mostly solved (except for understanding a few suboptions). What I'm really curious about is HierarchicalEdgeBundling.

Comment: Sorry I missed that link. Am curious about the `"HierarchicalEdgeBundling"` too. +1

Comment: Try this: `"EdgeLayout" -> {"HierarchicalEdgeBundling", "SplineWeight" -> Automatic}`.

Comment: @Silvia I really wonder why this is not advertised more! [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WgXty.png). Can you post an answer?

Comment: @Silvia Actually the key seems to have been not to specify a VertexLayout.  For some reason I always tried with a vertex layout ...

Comment: I image a specific `"SplineWeight"` setting would change the "strength" of the bundling, but I haven't found a legal syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find available settings other than `Automatic`, by which there seems no differences between `"SplineWeight"` and `"LCARemove"`:

```
elst = RandomGraph[{10, 30}] // EdgeList;
Graph[
                elst,
                VertexLabels -> "Name",
                GraphLayout -> {
                        "EdgeLayout" -> {
                                "HierarchicalEdgeBundling",
                                # -> Automatic
                                }
                        }
                ] & /@ {"SplineWeight", "LCARemove"} //
    FlipView
```

[image: Graph layout with "HierarchicalEdgeBundling"]

## Edit:

According to [halmir](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/590/halmir), `LCARemove` take `All` and `None`. `SplineWeight` is not supported.

Comment: In LCARemove, LCA stands for [lowest common ancestor](http://graphics.cs.illinois.edu/sites/default/files/edgebundles.pdf).  By trial and error, the values `None` and `All` work (and make a difference).

Comment: Yes, LCARemove take All and None.  SplineWeight is not supported...

Comment: Some discussion of LCA removal can be found here: http://www.win.tue.nl/vis1/home/dholten/papers/bundles_infovis.pdf

Comment: @halmir What about `DividedEdgeBundling`?  Could you explain some of the suboptions in an answer?

Comment: @halmir Thanks! I have added that in the answer, please feel free to edit it.

Comment: @halmir Two more questions: 1. [Is there a better way to handle custom attributes?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95935/12) Part of this question is whether it's easy to transfer one attribute into another one, e.g. import a GML then use a custom property as standard `EdgeCapacity`. 2. There's a disconnect between `WeightedAdjacencyGraph` and `WeightedAdjacencyMatrix` in that one represents missing edges with `Infinity`, the other with `0`. Is there some easy way to get them to use the same format? Can I choose whether I want to use Infinity or 0 for this purpose?