# Get or set vertex properties for all graph vertices at once

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am looking for a way to either get or set a vertex property for all vertices of the graph at once.  The two functions will be:

```
getVertexProp[g_?GraphQ, prop_] := ...
setVertexProp[g_?GraphQ, prop_, values_] := ...
```

`getVertexProp` must return a list of values.  Each value corresponds to the respective vertex in `VertexList[g]`.  When one particular vertex does not have this property, the list must contain `Missing["Nonexistent"]`.

`setVertexProp` must set a property when given a similar list.

#### Requirements

The functions must work with any property, either built-in or custom.  `getVertexProperty` should work even if a property is set only for some of the vertices.

I suggest testing the implementation at least with:

- Properties `VertexWeight`, `VertexStyle`, and `"foo"`.
- The two graphs `g1 = RandomGraph[{10,20}]` and `g2 = Graph[VertexList[g1], EdgeList[g1]]`.
- Setting the same property twice on both graphs above (to test overwriting).

#### Example implementation

```
getVertexProp[g_?GraphQ, prop_] := 
 Replace[PropertyValue[{g, #}, prop], $Failed -> Missing["Nonexistent"]] & /@ VertexList[g]

setVertexProp[g_?GraphQ, prop_, values_] :=
 If[
  Length[values] =!= VertexCount[g],
  $Failed,
  Fold[SetProperty[{#1, #2[[1]]}, prop -> #2[[2]]] &, g, Transpose[{VertexList[g], values}]]
 ]
```

I am looking for an implementation that performs better than these.

Benchmark:

```
g = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "BipartiteDiseasomeNetwork"}];

values = getVertexProp[g, "Type"]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0080, Null} *)

setVertexProp[g, "Foo", values]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {15.3572, Null} *)
```

`getVertexProp` is fine, but there is a potential for speedup.  Compare these two methods of retrieving edge properties:

```
rg = RandomGraph[{1000, 10000}, EdgeCapacity -> RandomReal[1, 10000]];

PropertyValue[{rg, #}, EdgeWeight -> EdgeCapacity] & /@ EdgeList[rg]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.040, Null} *)

WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[rg]["NonzeroValues"]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0000189, Null} *)
```

Unfortunately, this implementation of `setVertexProp` is unusably slow.

A different implementation could special-case [each type of graph property](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118196/12), but this is ugly and error-prone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pardon the rant, but IMO graph related property value infrastructure was poorly designed. The `Graph[]` api was created before the advent of Associations, and I don't think it has changed since version 8.0.

Anyway, PropertyValue is typically faster than SetProperty according to the docs, maybe this works for you:

```
ClearAll@setVertexProp;
setVertexProp[g_, prop_, vals_] := Module[{h=g, vl=VertexList@g},
    Do[PropertyValue[{h, vl[[i]]}, prop] = vals[[i]], {i,Length@vl}];
    Return @ h
]
```

And the timings:

```
g=ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph","BipartiteDiseasomeNetwork"}];
values = getVertexProp[g, "Type"]; 
res=test1[g,"Foo",values];//AbsoluteTiming
res===g

(* 
   {0.0307, Null}
   False
*)
```

Comment: The function should return a new graph object though, and leave the old one unmodified.  Can you fix this (make a copy at the beginning)?

Comment: @Szabolcs OK will do.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't run this through all of the use cases, but just to get the creative juices flowing:

```
setVertexPropSemiImperative[g_?GraphQ, prop_, values_List] :=
  Module[{vertices = VertexList[g] // Developer`FromPackedArray, i = 0}
  , If[Length[values] =!= Length[vertices]
    , $Failed
    , SetProperty[{g, vertices}, prop :> values[[++i]]]
    ]
  ]
```

Timings, on my machine:

```
setVertexProp[g, "Foo", values]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* 33.4833 *)

setVertexPropSemiImperative[g, "Foo", values]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.0413123 *)
```

**Notes**

`` Developer`FromPackedArray? `` is used here because it has been empirically shown that `SetProperty` will not accept a packed array of indices (in version 11.1 at least):

```
SetProperty[{WheelGraph[3], {1, 2, 3}}, "foo" -> 999]
(* ... a graph ... *)

SetProperty[{WheelGraph[3], {1, 2, 3} // Developer`ToPackedArray}, "foo" -> 999]
(* $Failed *)
```

The `VertexList` of the graph in the question is not a packed array.  But some graph types have a packed vertex list, e.g.

```
PetersenGraph[] // VertexList // Developer`PackedArrayQ
(* True *)
```

Comment: `h = PetersenGraph[]; setVertexPropSemiImperative[h, "foo", Range[10]]` fails for me

Comment: @M.R. Yes, for me too.  Strange...  I am investigating.

Comment: I do not fully understand why this should work. I don't think `v` can be a list of vertices in `SetProperty[{g, v}, ...]`. At least that did not work in any examples I tried.

Comment: @M.R. It fails because `SetProperty[{PetersenGraph[], Range[10]}, "foo" -> 999]` fails.  Yet `SetProperty[{PetersenGraph[], {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}, "foo" -> 999]` works.  It is as if `SetProperty` was `HoldAll`, but it isn't.  It _is_ a kernel function though, so there appears to be some black magic (emphasis on "black").

Comment: @Szabolcs The documentation claims that a list of vertices is "typically" valid, as is `All` and a pattern.  However, I could not get the latter two to work.  And, as @M.R. points out, indexes do not always work either.

Comment: ``SetProperty[{PetersenGraph[], Developer`FromPackedArray@Range[10]}, 
 "foo" -> 999]`` works.

Comment: Property handling is just so messed up.  This works BTW but it doesn't solve all my problems: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96024/12

Comment: @M.R. I have applied a fix for packed arrays to my response and added an addendum about packing woes.  This response is now more about strange behaviour than a practical solution, but I will leave it here for posterity.

Comment: I keep looking at the documentation, but it is not clear from it why a vertex list should work in SetProperty. It is the packing bug why I thought it shouldn't.  These is the description about an *itemspec* that has the form {*colletion*, *index*}, but that did not seem to apply here.

Comment: @Szabolcs The docs say that _itemspec_ has the form _{collection, index}_ and that _index_ is "typically" one of _ind_, _{ind1, ind2, ...}_, `All`, or _patt_.  I first tried `All` (the supposed default) and _patt_, but neither worked.  The explicit index list "worked" (kind of, sort of).

Comment: Based on that I would expect a syntax like `{obj, {collection, index}}`, but instead we have `{obj, item}`. I think the `{collection, index}` syntax is for `MeshRegion`s.  For graphs, it says that items can be vertices or edges (last line undr Details).

Comment: Like this: `mr = DelaunayMesh[RandomReal[1, {20, 2}]];
PropertyValue[{mr, {2, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}}, MeshCellMeasure]`.  Here `obj` is the mesh region, `collection` is `2`, which means 2-dimensional things, i.e. the polygons, and `{1,2,3,4,5}` are the indexes (not names) of the polygons to consider.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57124/discussion-between-wreach-and-szabolcs).